# Is there a chart that displays browser usage in different sectors, for instance local authorities?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, statistics, cross-browser

I'm a frontend web developer working for a company at the moment that has a lot of RIA design going on in the backend but it also caters almost entirely for UK local authorities and social workers.

For those of you not too enlightened about local authorities/councils here in the UK, they tend to be rather slow on the uptake of new technologies, and therefore this clashes slightly with the cutting edge the company is trying to purvey.

Therefore, it would be helpful for information about how browser usage is broken down in all sectors (since I also freelance) to give me an idea of how much leverage I have to hand in convincing the suits not to support IE6.

Comment: I can only assume that you would need to have access to a database that stored an IP address to a company and another table that associated that company to a specific sector(s). Then all you would have to do is grab the ip from the user. I don't know if such a table is available to the public and updated frequently enough to be useful.

Comment: Just a note, I've just found out that the next version of our product won't be supporting IE6 and most users will be asked to upgrade to at least IE7! Stoked! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Here are some [general](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) [charts](http://ejohn.org/blog/determining-browser-market-share/).
- Here's a [GUI chart](http://gs.statcounter.com/) where you can select country / region.
- [Here are excerpts (PDF)](http://www.e-janco.com/Samples/BrowserSample.pdf) from a whitepaper on business site browser use (business sector only).
- Finally, here is an [archive of global browser statistics](http://www.thecounter.com/stats/) by month.

I cannot for the life of me find any statistics broken down by sector / local authority.  Sorry!

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering whether there was anything sector specific.